# Apache ActiveMQ priorityBackup switching detection C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, activemq-classic, nms

I am currently using NMS (C#), and I provide it with three server addresses with a priority server with the expectation for it to connect to the 2nd or 3rd server when the main is offline and then re-connect with the main server once back online.

I am using the following nugets:

- Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ (1.8.0)
- Apache.NMS (1.8.0)
- Broker version 5.16.4 (I think)

Connection string:

```
failover:(tcp://mainServer:61619,tcp://backup1:61619,tcp://backup2:61619)?randomize=false&timeout=10000&backup=true&priorityBackup=true&useExponentialBackOff=true&reconnectDelayExponent=2.0&initialReconnectDelay=5000&initialReconnectDelay=180000&consumerExpiryCheckEnabled=false
```

When the main server goes offline, I expect it to trigger an event to state that it is switching. Is there any way to detect when it switches back and forth between servers?

Comment: I am using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ 1.8.0 and Apache.NMS 1.8.0 nugets using .NET 6.

Comment: I think it's 5.16.2 - 5.16.4

Comment: There are to many questions here to provide an answer that isn't a full documenting of the client library. you need to narrow your focus

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the main focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you haven't bothered to look at the actual NMS.API source as the answers are all there.  The [IConnection](https://github.com/apache/activemq-nms-api/blob/main/src/nms-api/IConnection.cs) has events for what you are looking to accomplish:

```
/// <summary>
/// A delegate that is used by Fault tolerant NMS Implementation to notify their
/// clients that the Connection is not currently active to due some error.
/// </summary>
public delegate void ConnectionInterruptedListener();

/// <summary>
/// A delegate that is used by Fault tolerant NMS Implementation to notify their
/// clients that the Connection that was interrupted has now been restored.
/// </summary>
public delegate void ConnectionResumedListener();
```

And:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// An asynchronous listener that is notified when a Fault tolerant connection
    /// has been interrupted.
    /// </summary>
    event ConnectionInterruptedListener ConnectionInterruptedListener;

    /// <summary>
    /// An asynchronous listener that is notified when a Fault tolerant connection
    /// has been resumed.
    /// </summary>
    event ConnectionResumedListener ConnectionResumedListener;
```

Comment: I have those implemented, but I do not know if they trigger when it switches server.

Comment: That is the intent, you can of course test it to be sure.

Comment: I will update this post when I can confirm it. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: The Unit tests for NMS.ActiveMQ can also enlighten you on the working of the client, and would seem to validate that this is how the events are fired.

Comment: I blocked the IP address of the main server and it did trigger the interrupt. I have unblocked the IP address and unfortunately didn't switch back to the primary, so I will have to implement that.

Comment: Failover in ActiveMQ clients doesn't work that way, there is no primary only "the one you are connected to now"